# Getting logstash to write certain logs to a file

Tags: linux, ubuntu-server, elasticsearch

I am trying to get logs from my shadowsocks docker into a file so that it can be integrated with fail2ban. The container outputs logs to stdout, which is already integrated with my ELK stack (also docker) through docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  shadowsocks:
    image: shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev
    ...
    logging:
      driver: gelf
      options:
        gelf-address: "udp://10.0.0.1:12201"
        tag: "shadowsocks"
```

I thought the simplest way to write the shadowsocks logs to a file would be through logstash, the output for which is configured as such:

```
output {
    redis {
        host => "redis-cache"
        data_type => "list"
        key => "logstash"
    }

    if [tag] == "shadowsocks" {
        file {
            path => "/tmp/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}.log"
            codec => json
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this never writes any logs. I think that the problem is the conditional statement `if [tag] == "shadowsocks"` because when I remove this, it writes to the log file just fine (of course, it's then writing EVERYTHING to the log file, not only shadowsocks logs).

What am I doing wrong and how can I get logstash to write only shadowsocks logs to the file?